# IIS 7 "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found" was working fine with php, asp.net

Tags: iis

Everything was working fine till i tried to put a binding for https. After that every resource which was served before returns: HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found

I reverted the settings but to no avail! Any ideas? System restore?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to start the application

https://www.znetlive.com/kb/2454A/technical-support/webserver-related-issues/i-am-getting-http-error-404-the-requested-resource-is-not-found-what-should-i-do.html